# Rails respond_with working incorrectly with json

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to update a record remotely (via ajax), and get a response which includes the serialized record, but I am continually getting xhr.responseText = {} . I would like to receive a serialized version of the updated record.

Here is my view form...

```
=semantic_form_for theme, :html => {'data-type' => 'json', :id => :theme_display_type_form, :remote => true} do |form|
    -form.inputs do
        =form.input :display_type
```

The controller which processes...

```
respond_to :html, :json

... other actions...

def update
   flash[:success] = "Theme was successfully updated" if theme.update_attributes params[:theme]
   respond_with(theme)
end
```

and then the response is caught by the rails.js ajax:success event

```
$('#theme_display_type_form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
   var responseObject = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
   alert(xhr.responseText); // = {}
   alert(responseObject); // = null
});
```

I must be missing something. Can anyone inform me of what I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

It looks like I may be having an issue with '**respond_with**' as using the old respond_to method in my controller works properly...

```
def update
   flash[:success] = "Theme was successfully updated" if theme.update_attributes params[:theme]
   respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => theme }
   end
end
```

Anyone have any ideas why respond_with not working properly?

---

**ANSWER**

as per the lighthouse posting on https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5199-respond_with-returns-on-put-and-delete-verb

it is normal that an UPDATE will return no object, since you already have the object in your possession..

Answer (score 0):

I do have problems with respond_with but respond_to works correctly.

I see it in POST (create).  It seems like respond_with works sometimes...